# Get element from array by reference

Tags: arrays, swift

I have an array filled with structs. Let's say I want to change the first element of the array it if exists. I expected that something like this works:

```
if var first = &unconfirmedDataFromSocket.first {
    first.markAsResend() // some mutating func
}
```

But I get this error:

`Use of extraneous '&'`

Is it possible in Swift to do what I want? Ofcourse there is an ugly workaround:

1. Remove the `&`
2. After calling markAsResend, remove the first element of the array and add the `first` variable

But I was hoping for something more nicer.

Comment: I regard `if !unconfirmedDataFromSocket.isEmpty {  unconfirmedDataFromSocket[0].markAsResend() }`  not as ugly.

Comment: @RajaKishan I get this error: Cannot use mutating member on immutable value: 'first' is a get-only property

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to subscript the array by index to be able to mutate its elements directly. To ensure that the index is actually valid, you can use `indices.contains` or for the 1st element specifically, you can simply check that `isEmpty` is `false`.

```
if !unconfirmedDataFromSocket.isEmpty {
    unconfirmedDataFromSocket[0].markAsRead()
}
```

Or using `indices` (this works for elements other than the 1st as well):

```
let index = 0
if unconfirmedDataFromSocket.indices.contains(index) {
    unconfirmedDataFromSocket[index].markAsRead()
}
```